# How to get a specific Json value in a String variable - Java?

Tags: java, json, api

I have a java app which calls evepraisal's API to get a specific "price" for an item :
this is my code :

```
String url =  "https://evepraisal.com/appraisal.json";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
   // con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "market=jita&raw_textarea=tritanium&persist=no&format=json";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);



    String sellPrice = jsonObject.getJSONObject("totals").getString("sell");

    System.out.println("sell price " + sellPrice);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

console output:

```
{
"appraisal":{
  "created":1582370316,
  "kind":"listing",
  "market_name":"jita",
  "totals":{
     "buy":7.09,
     "sell":7.29,
     "volume":0.01

},
  "items":[
     {
        "name":"tritanium",
        "typeID":34,
        "typeName":"Tritanium",
        "typeVolume":0.01,
        "quantity":1,
        "prices":{
           "all":{
              "avg":7.825135725671236,
              "max":6660,
              "median":8.49,
              "min":0.01,
              "percentile":10,
              "stddev":12.094503046356275,
              "volume":21067715118,
              "order_count":83

},
           "buy":{
              "avg":4.4427463532321685,
              "max":7.09,
              "median":5,
              "min":0.01,
              "percentile":7.01,
              "stddev":1.243253441213804,
              "volume":3668335637,
              "order_count":34

},
           "sell":{
              "avg":8.817038715163093,
              "max":6660,
              "median":8.49,
              "min":7.29,
              "percentile":7.32,
              "stddev":13.20791605306975,
              "volume":17399379481,
              "order_count":49

},
           "updated":"2020-02-22T11:16:22.644986932Z",
           "strategy":"orders"
```

I want to get this specific value into a String var : Appraisal --> total --> Sell = 7.29
I think my problem comes from getJSONObject line. I've found multiple tutorials online but none answered correctly my needs,
Sometimes i've got a

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["totals"] not found.
```

refering to

```
String sellPrice = jsonObject.getJSONObject("totals").getString("sell");
```

If someone has a piste
What I am doing wrong ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Surely you need to `.getJSONObject("appraisal")` first?

Comment: JSONObject["appraisal"] not found when try to do that

Comment: Did you try using Gson ? It would convert your JSON to objects directly and then you can get any value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

Variable `response` is empty, right?

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
jsonObject.getJSONObject("appraisal").getJSONObject("totals").getDouble("sell");
```

Comment: True, I don't know why because System.out.println(response.toString()) in the end isn't empty and contains Json file

Comment: @lolottegarcia because you create the jsonObject BEFORE appending lines to `response`

Comment: @lolottegarcia Did you use org.json or fastjson? My demo is based on fastjson.

Comment: Ok mate, I use JSON JSONObject.parseObject : cannot resolve symbol (first line) I understand what you are tryintg to do, how can I do a JSONObject.parseObject without this specific command ?

Comment: @lolottegarcia Ok, so I'm supposing you are using org.json. Try this:
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());`

Comment: Genius. Thanks. Do you know how can a reduce a Bigdecimal size ? like instead of getting 7.2929595994949... I only want 7.29. sellPrice.size or .lenght doesn't seems to work here

Comment: @lolottegarcia Try using double instead of Bigdecimal. Answer updated.
Also, to reduce a bigDecimal, use `bigDecimal.setScale()`.

`BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("7.2929595994949");
BigDecimal bigDecimal1 = bigDecimal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(bigDecimal1);`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.toString());
double sell = (double)jsonObject.getJSONObject("appraisal").getJSONObject("totals")
              .getDouble("sell");
```

Comment: @ lolottegarcia, do you want sell value in String type variable?